# docker inspect --format "{{json .State.Health }}" keeps showing status unhealthy, what's the criteria to determine the status healthy/unhealthy?

Tags: asp.net-core, docker-compose, azure-pipelines, docker-healthcheck

I am running this in Azure DevOps pipeline.

I have a `healthcheck` in my docker compose like so:

```
    healthcheck:
      test: "ps aux | grep 'dotnet test' | grep -v grep | tr -d '\n' && exit 0 || exit 1" #check if dotnet test process is running
      interval: 2s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 20
      start_period: 1s
```

When I inspect the status using `docker inspect --format "{{json .State.Health }}" my-service-name | jq`

```
{
  "Status": "unhealthy",
  "FailingStreak": 0,
  "Log": [
    {
      "Start": "2023-04-11T01:23:19.629448812Z",
      "End": "2023-04-11T01:23:19.730674224Z",
      "ExitCode": 0,
      "Output": "root           1 20.0  2.6 274357724 186164 ?    Ssl  01:22   0:06 dotnet test ./FunctionalTests.csproj -c Release --collect:XPlat Code Coverage --settings ../coverlet.runsettings.xml --results-directory:/TestResults"
    },
    {
      "Start": "2023-04-11T01:23:21.733819151Z",
      "End": "2023-04-11T01:23:21.805409101Z",
      "ExitCode": 0,
      "Output": "root           1 18.7  2.6 274357728 186292 ?    Ssl  01:22   0:06 dotnet test ./FunctionalTests.csproj -c Release --collect:XPlat Code Coverage --settings ../coverlet.runsettings.xml --results-directory:/TestResults"
    },
    {
      "Start": "2023-04-11T01:23:23.809734109Z",
      "End": "2023-04-11T01:23:23.911799349Z",
      "ExitCode": 0,
      "Output": "root           1 17.7  2.6 274324644 186236 ?    Ssl  01:22   0:06 dotnet test ./FunctionalTests.csproj -c Release --collect:XPlat Code Coverage --settings ../coverlet.runsettings.xml --results-directory:/TestResults"
    },
    {
      "Start": "2023-04-11T01:23:25.915794952Z",
      "End": "2023-04-11T01:23:26.020336032Z",
      "ExitCode": 0,
      "Output": "root           1 16.7  2.6 274324644 186236 ?    Ssl  01:22   0:06 dotnet test ./FunctionalTests.csproj -c Release --collect:XPlat Code Coverage --settings ../coverlet.runsettings.xml --results-directory:/TestResults"
    },
    {
      "Start": "2023-04-11T01:23:28.024208233Z",
      "End": "2023-04-11T01:23:28.146991706Z",
      "ExitCode": 0,
      "Output": "root           1 15.8  2.6 274308240 186208 ?    Ssl  01:22   0:06 dotnet test ./FunctionalTests.csproj -c Release --collect:XPlat Code Coverage --settings ../coverlet.runsettings.xml --results-directory:/TestResults"
    }
  ]
}
```

See the "Status" there says "unhealthy", even though all the exit codes are `0` and "FailingStreak" is `0`.

My question is **why**?

The healthcheck seems to work though, it correctly notices the required service is up, so everything works fine.

But that Status '**unhealthy**' is keeping me awake at night.